# Limit the amount of events shown on react big calendar (month view)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

I am trying to implement a calendar on my website which has multiple events per day. I want to only show one event per day, and have the + # more link below it for the rest, is there any styling fix I can do to make that possible? Now it will always show two events, but when it gets to three events I see + 2 more.

I have tried changing some heights of elements to make the calender limit them, but any combination I have tried has kept it the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.